# VBScript alternative of PHP's debug_backtrace

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an old **VBScript** project I need to debug and due to it's complexity  I cannot see where are some functions being called from. Is there any **VBScript** alternative to PHP's **debug_backtrace** function or similar to see the stack trace?

Comment: Will [Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  help ? It will show the name of the executing file (not the name of the include file)

Comment: ...good thinking, thx. but that only gives me the current script page name rather that the actual function call reference I need which originates elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**So at this point, after a lot of searching, I am going to answer my own question as follows:** VBScript is relatively old language and does not seem to have any built-in function/method or other means which would reliably return stack trace of function call (similar to PHP's **debug_backtrace()** function.

I managed to track the execution path with a simple, custom **Function logBreakPointToFile()** which I wrote and I placed throughout 100s of .asp files (everywhere where the method in question was referenced directly and indirectly - nested). This gave me a very messy idea what was actually happening. However is cost me a lot of prep. time and clean-up time which I was trying to avoid in the first place.

If anyone finds a better solution, please share.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

VBScript does not throw any exception with stacktrace information in case of error.

@Runtime, in case of error, VBScript throws an **Err** object.

Ex: Below script will throw 'Division by zero' error & script will not get executed further.

```
Msgbox 5/0
Msgbox "Hello"  'This will not execute
```

**On Error**:

VBScript uses 'On Error Resume Next' statement which starts the error handler. It means, in case of error just skip current line and goto the next line. 'On Error GoTo 0' disables the current error handler. (like you are closing an 'if' block). Please check  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx)  for more details.

Consider this example.

```
On Error Resume Next

Msgbox 5/0
Msgbox "Hello"  'This will say "Hello"

Msgbox Err.Number    '11
Msgbox err.Description  'division by zero

On Error GoTo 0    'stops the error handler. any run time error after this will stop the program
```

Err.Number will be 0 in case no error is found.

So, You can have function like

```
Function Divide(ByVal A, ByVal B)
  On Error Resume Next 
  Dim Result
  Result = A/B
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
      Divide = Result
  Else
      Divide = "Infinite"
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
End function
```

Remember this - as it simply goes to the next line in case of error,

```
On Error Resume Next

If 5/0 Then
   Msgbox "???"     'This will get executed. It does not go to Else
Else
   Msgbox "Hello"    'It will not show this
End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: thanks, the thing is I have no errors, I just have unusually high volume of functions called which creates unacceptable overhead. Some functions seem to be called on loop. Since the project is quite large, I would have to sort through 100's of files to keep figuring out where is it being called from. So unfortunately I do not have any errors I can go by (that would be too easy :)

Comment: `MsgBox()` will not work in Classic ASP use `Response.Write()` instead. These examples assume your writing standalone VBScript or client side VBScript. In fact using it will cause an exception itself hiding the actual issue.

Comment: @Lankymart...so how would I use it? Let's say I insert response.write("message") statement into the function and run the application. I will get 23 "message"s printed on top of the screen, I know it is being called 23 times but I still do not know where from...

Comment: @Milan If you have setup error pages to show detailed errors in IIS, then you should get detailed errors pointing to the line in your code that triggered the error this is the best you can hope for.

Comment: ..but that's the thing, I do not have any errors. The problem is excessive function calling slowing the application down. That's why I am trying to figure out where are those functions called from.

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure IIS to send errors to the browser.  Its under Classic ASP settings on IIS 7 - 8.  You have the option to send errors to browser on local requests, or all requests.  For testing on a dev box usually its set for local.  It will tell you what line number you are erroring out on.

As for getting more detail on what functions are slowing your application down.  With classic asp you need to write your own timing code to measure such metrics.